# GDI+ Exception on Bitmap.Save

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, gdi+

I want to save my resized image, but I'm getting a GDI+ error. The code:

```
        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(path));
        float aspectRatio = (float)image.Size.Width / (float)image.Size.Height;
        int newHeight = 200;
        int newWidth = Convert.ToInt32(aspectRatio * newHeight);
        System.Drawing.Bitmap thumbBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        System.Drawing.Graphics thumbGraph = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(thumbBitmap);
        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
        thumbBitmap.Save("~/images/galeria/thumb/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
        thumbGraph.Dispose();
        thumbBitmap.Dispose();
        image.Dispose();
```

Error is caused by this line:

```
thumbBitmap.Save("~/images/galeria/thumb/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

EDIT1:

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: Please, give us full error description.

Comment: Debugger. Breakpoints. Use them and maybe, could you give us the full error?

Comment: Sure it is a valid path? got write privileges?

Comment: The path exists. Whole error inside EDIT1.

Answer (score 2):

You have several things wrong with your code:

```
thumbBitmap.Save("~/images/galeria/thumb/" + FileUpload1.FileName);
```

1. You can only use the `~` character in paths that go through `HttpServerUtility.MapPath` (i.e. `this.Server.MapPath`). GDI expects a valid Win32 filename. You need to translate the filename first.
2. You cannot trust the `FileName` property of a uploaded file: Some versions of Internet Explorer provide the complete local filename, which means your path will be `.../galeria/thumb/D:\Me\myfile.jpg` which is not valid. Other web-browsers will often provide a fake name and only preserve the file extension. You also cannot trust the user to provide a correct extension. What happens if the user uploads a malicious file which can be interpreted as a valid bitmap, but is ALSO a valid PHP script which wipes your server's HDD?
3. You should always prefer `using` blocks over explicitly calling the `Dispose` method.
4. Import the `System.Drawing` namespace so you're not specifying the full type name in code.
5. You're saving the thumbnail as a bitmap, these are large uncompressed files. You should compress them as a JPEG or PNG image. You were also saving the image with the file extension of the original image (which you cannot trust).

Here's how I would improve it:

```csharp
using( Image image = Image.FromFile( Server.MapPath( path ) ) ) {

    float aspectRatio = (float)image.Size.Width / (float)image.Size.Height;
    int newHeight = 200;
    int newWidth = (ToInt32)( aspectRatio * newHeight );

    using( Bitmap thumbBitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap( newWidth, newHeight ) )
    using( Graphics thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage( thumbBitmap ) ) {

        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        Rectangle imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        thumbGraph.DrawImage( image, imageRectangle );

        String outputFileName = this.Server.MapPath( "~/images/galeria/thumb" );
        outputFileName = Path.Combine( outputFileName, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( path ) ) + ".jpg";

        // Use code from here to save as a JPEG: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583(v=vs.110).aspx
        thumbBitmap.Save( outputFileName, jpegEncoder, jpegEncoderParameters );
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving me GDI+ error on InterpolationMode, but if I comment it then it gives and GDI+ error on Rectangle.